# If i am having the 5 pages with 5 controllers in angularjs

Tags: angularjs, cordova

Hi i am having the 5 pages with 5 controllers and i am using the one service using injection  in every controller . Is it possible to do without editing a code in views and controllers  to stop the services functionality by writing code anywhere once in the any of one view or controller ?
For example I am having a app which uses the server to retrieve the data and i can writing a simple code to restrict that service instead of server i can access my localdata ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All [Angular services](http://docs.angularjs.org/guide/dev_guide.services.creating_services) are application singletons. This means, you can change state of the service once, and the change will be 'visible' to all it's users.

The service gets instantiated when application will ask for it. While the service exists, all the controllers, etc. will receive a reference to the same service instance (I would still expect the service to be garbage collected when all the references to the service are lost).

This means, after you initialize the service, all controllers can invoke methods, etc. - all on the same instance, visible to all other instances.

Here's a [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ellitereit/HXfAU/3/) showing the concept. When the value in factory object is changed in one controller, it is visible throughout the application. Both controllers use the modified value of testFactory.name, as it gets modified during the initialization of HelloCtrl. It is fairly easy to add two buttons that would count clicks in a field of factory's object and make both controllers display the value as it changes.

```
function HelloCtrl($scope, testFactory)
{
    $scope.fromFactory = testFactory.sayHello();
    testFactory.setName("ellitereit");
    $scope.newValue = testFactory.sayHello();
}

function GoodbyeCtrl($scope, testFactory)
{
    $scope.fromFactory = testFactory.sayGoodbye();
}
```

Comment: If possible can you please give brief explanation please @ellitereit

Comment: I expanded the answer. There's a jsFiddle that shows the concept in action.

Comment: Thanks for the brief answer.I can understand it. But my use case is 
Am developing an android mobile app. I have my first page with to options 1.to connect to a remote server(web server residing in a network computer) 2.to access the localhost server(within the android mobile).

Comment: and i have 5 different pages with five different controllers each accessing a common service for accessing the data from a server.
i have to optimize only that common service so that if i provide any server ip it should get the data from that server using the $http sevice, or if the server ip is not provided then the data should come from within the localstorage of the app. Can u help me with this?